# Why it is easier to draw on some grids?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, computational-geometry

[image]

I would like to know is there any way to prove that drawing in a grid on the left would be more precise than in a grid on the right. For me, that make sense since we have more points on the left. But, is there a mathematical way to prove something like this?

Comment: You first need to say what you mean by drawing (and by precision).

Comment: @MishaLavrov I meant intuitively, for example if a child wants to draw something it seems the figure on the left will be more similar to what child wanted to draw. We can also ask if we want to draw only by connecting points of intersection of vertical and horizontal lines, would we get a "better" shape. For example, circle or parabola? Is there a mathematical proof for such a kind of relation between grids and shapes we draw in them?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the middle two lines of your left grid, there is a point every $\frac 12$ unit while on the right there is only a point every unit.  Once you extend the grid enough beyond the boundary of an area, there will be about twice as many points inside the area with the grid on the left.  However, the blocks on the left have the same area of one square unit as the blocks on the right.

You have not defined what style of drawing you are doing or how you define precision.  Are you allowed to select line segments from each grid to make the drawing?  Do you fill in blocks to color an area?  Do you connect dots that are defined by the grid with lines?  In the third case, as the left grid has all the points of the right grid and more, you must be able to be more precise.  In the first and second, it probably depends on what picture you are trying to draw.  If it follows the grid lines on the right, the left will introduce jaggies for vertical lines.

Comment: I meant intuitively, for example if a child wants to draw something it seems the figure on the left will be more similar to what child wanted to draw. We can also ask if we want to draw only by connecting points of intersection of vertical and horizontal lines, would we get a "better" shape. For example, circle or parabola? Is there a mathematical proof for such a kind of relation between grids and shapes we draw in them?

Comment: If I can draw diagonals, there are more diagonals on the left because there are more points, so we can fit a curve more accurately on the left.  Is that what you are looking for?  Contrast that with a requirement to follow the grid lines, where if the desired line is vertical the right grid can reproduce it nicely while the left has to have a lot of stairsteps.  When you ask for a mathematical proof, you need to define what you want to prove.